# WPF Dynamically set control column and row within nested grid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to dynamically add nested grids in WPF, but I'm having an issue setting the column/row position for the 2nd child grid as 'Grid.Setrow(element,value)' applies the rule to all grids rather than my specific instance. I have tried 'MyGridName.Setrow(element,value)' but this throws an error saying that the member cannot be accessed from an instance (because the Setrow property is static). Am I missing anything, or does anybody have a work around so nested grids can be added dynamically?

```
// Initiate Outer Grid
            Grid ChartOuter = new Grid();
            ChartCont.Children.Add(ChartOuter);
            ColumnDefinition[] columns = new ColumnDefinition[3];
            RowDefinition[] rows = new RowDefinition[3];

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                columns[i] = new ColumnDefinition();
                ChartOuter.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columns[i]);
                rows[i] = new RowDefinition();
                ChartOuter.RowDefinitions.Add(rows[i]);
            }

// Initiate Inner Grid
            Grid ChartInner = new Grid();
            ChartOuter.Children.Add(ChartInner);

            Border EdgeBorder = new Border()
            {
                BorderThickness = new Thickness()
                {
                    Bottom = 2,
                    Left = 0,
                    Right = 2,
                    Top =  0
                },
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray)
            };
            ChartInner.Children.Add(EdgeBorder);


            ColumnDefinition[] columnsinner = new ColumnDefinition[MaxCandles];
            RowDefinition[] rowsinner = new RowDefinition[500];

            for (int i = 0; i < MaxCandles; i++)
            {
                columnsinner[i] = new ColumnDefinition();
                columnsinner[i].Width = new GridLength(9);
                ChartInner.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnsinner[i]);
                // Grid Lines
                if (i % XLabelDenom == 0)
                {
                    Border gridlines = new Border()
                    {
                        BorderThickness = new Thickness()
                        {
                            Bottom = 0,
                            Left = 1,
                            Right = 0,
                            Top = 0
                        },
                        BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray)
                    };

                    ChartInner.Children.Add(gridlines);
                    Grid.SetColumn(gridlines, i);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Whats `gridlines`? it need to be a child of `ChartInner` at least. The `SetColumn` static method is used to set the attached properties. But they are used in the first most grid parent

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Sorry - had removed some relevant code with the irrelevant code. I've edited it now. gridlines is a border and child of InnerChart. When you say the the setcolumn method is used for the first most grid parent, does that mean only ever the first parent, or the most recently declared?

Comment: The most recently declared.

Comment: `rowsinner` isn't used yet/anymore? Also are you aware that you add the `EdgeBorder` to the grid, which make it col=0,row=0. Next to that, I don't see nothing strange.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Ah! Thanks Jeroen, that was my mistake! EdgeBorder was in column and row 0, which worked as I expected until I added the other columns and rows.